# Error in cloud_firestore_platform_interface after Flutter SDK upgrade

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I recently upgraded my Flutter SDK to the latest version, and I'm encountering an error related to the cloud_firestore_platform_interface package. Despite trying various solutions, I haven't been able to resolve the issue

```
/C:/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:71: Error: Expected ';' after this.
dynamic _findKeyValueInMap(String key, Map<String, dynamic> map) {p
                                                                      ^
                                                                      ^
../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart:87:71: Error: The getter 'p' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentSnapshotPlatform'.
 - 'DocumentSnapshotPlatform' is from 'package:cloud_firestore_platform_interface/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart' ('../../../AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.flutter-io.cn/cloud_firestore_platform_interface-6.1.0/lib/src/platform_interface/platform_interface_document_snapshot.dart').      
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'p'.
    dynamic _findKeyValueInMap(String key, Map<String, dynamic> map) {p
```

Steps Taken:

Upgraded and downgraded the `cloud_firestore` package.
Executed
`flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and `flutter run`.
Checked FlutterFire compatibility.
Switched Flutter channels.
Despite these efforts, the issue persists. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.